# Random colors in Python

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm having a problem getting this program to work. The output is supposed to randomly fill each square with a random color from the list of 10 colors that I have, but each square is filled with the initial color only. I need to keep the definition of `pick_color()` the same as the professor's as he asked us to keep it the same. FYI also, each square gets incrementally smaller, with largest one getting drawn first.

BTW, I am asking because the professors encouraged me to, yet I didn't receive help that was beneficial when I posted on our school's piazza. And I have searched StackOverFlow and other sources for a solution, but to no avail.

```
import turtle
import random

squares = input("How many squares should I draw (whole numbers): ")
squares_int = int(squares)

def pick_color():
    colors = ["blue","black","brown","red","yellow","green","orange","beige","turquoise","pink"]
    random.shuffle(colors)
    return colors[0]

random_color = pick_color()
print(random_color)

length = 400
x = -200
y = 200

for i in range(squares_int):
    turtle.fillcolor(random_color)
    turtle.pensize(5)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.setx(x)
    turtle.sety(y)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.down()
    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.forward(length)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(length)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(length)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(length)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.end_fill()
    turtle.up()

    length = length - 30
    x = x + 15
    y = y - 15
```

It would be great if I just got a hint or two. I'm not looking for a straight-up answer. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: since you only call ``pick_color`` once, you only get one random color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you must call it inside the loop, you call it the first time so it will never change.

```
import turtle
import random

squares = input("How many squares should I draw (whole numbers): ")
squares_int = int(squares)

def pick_color():
    colors = ["blue","black","brown","red","yellow","green","orange","beige","turquoise","pink"]
    random.shuffle(colors)
    return colors[0]


length = 400
x = -200
y = 200

for i in range(squares_int):
    random_color = pick_color()
    turtle.fillcolor(random_color)
    turtle.pensize(5)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.setx(x)
    turtle.sety(y)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.down()
    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.forward(length)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(length)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(length)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(length)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.end_fill()
    turtle.up()

    length = length - 30
    x = x + 15
    y = y - 15
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you mind if I ask why i  have to call it again? I thought that that was what i was doing in turtle.fillcolor(random_color)

Comment: You just called it the first time so you'll only have one value and it will never change, and that's what you do not want.

Comment: Gotcha! I appreciate the help

Comment: @user7433120 If my answer helps you mark it as correct please.

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and you have just created a poor implementation of `random.choice`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 The OP is not the implementation of the function but the change of color.

Comment: If you read what @user7433120 wrote, he says explicitly that he does not want to change the pick_color function. But see how you can change the colors of each rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @TigerhawkT3 (+1) that your professor's implementation of `pick_color()` is crap. But I don't believe that `random.choice()`, nor your professor's way of abusing `random.shuffle()`, is the best option.  The issue with both is you can get the same color on successive calls which is what you don't want when drawing squares within squares:

```
>>> import random
>>> COLORS = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'black', 'pink', 'gold', 'violet', 'orange', 'magenta', 'cyan']
>>> for _ in range(10):
...     print(random.choice(COLORS))
... 
green
pink
red
black
violet
orange
orange
violet
yellow
yellow
>>>
```

I'd still use `random.shuffle()`, though not the way your professor did, with the addtional fix of keeping track of the returned color to make sure the last color of the previous shuffle isn't the first color of the new shuffle:

```
import turtle
import random

COLORS = ["blue", "black", "brown", "red", "yellow", "green", "orange", "beige", "turquoise", "pink"]

def pick_color(colors=[], previous=[None]):  # intentionally dangerous default values
    if not colors:
        colors.extend(COLORS)
        random.shuffle(colors)
        if colors[-1] == previous[0]:
            colors.insert(0, colors.pop())

    previous[0] = colors.pop()

    return previous[0]


squares = input("How many squares should I draw (whole numbers): ")
squares_int = int(squares)

length = 400
x = -200
y = 200

turtle.pensize(5)

for i in range(squares_int):
    random_color = pick_color()
    turtle.fillcolor(random_color)

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(x, y)
    turtle.pendown()

    turtle.begin_fill()
    for _ in range(4):
        turtle.forward(length)
        turtle.right(90)
    turtle.end_fill()

    length -= 30
    x, y = x + 15, y - 15

turtle.done()
```

I believe this produces a better result than the one you displayed with adjacent squares with the same color:

[image]

Comment: I appreciate the input; however, I have to use my professors implementation, and definition.

Answer (score 0):

`pick_color` creates a list of colors, shuffles them, then returns the first one, which you [use repeatedly](http://xkcd.com/221/). Instead, define that list at the top/global level, and pick a random color with `random.choice`:

```
turtle.fillcolor(random.choice(colors))
```

Comment: If someone could explain what's wrong with this answer to make it deserve a downvote, I would love to improve it.